# toggle fast issue

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a toggle function which works well except in the case where you try to click too fast each individual toggle content is not updated quickly enough.

I've tried keeping track of click-able state and also tried unbinding click, but can't bind it back since toggle is not an event handler.

Javascript:

```
                $('#toggleImages').toggle(function() {
                    $('#ip').fadeOut(200, function () {
                        $('#en').fadeIn(200, function() {
                            $('#swap').attr("src", "t1.png");
                        });
                    });
                }, function () {
                    $('#en').fadeOut(200, function () {
                        $('#ip').fadeIn(200, function() {
                            $('#swap').attr("src", "t2.png");
                        });
                    });
                });
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using `.stop()` :

```
$('#toggleImages').toggle(function() {
                    $('#ip').stop().fadeOut(200, function () {
                        $('#en').stop().fadeIn(200, function() {
                            $('#swap').attr("src", "t1.png");
                        });
                    });
                }, function () {
                    $('#en').stop().fadeOut(200, function () {
                        $('#ip').stop().fadeIn(200, function() {
                            $('#swap').attr("src", "t2.png");
                        });
                    });
                });
```